# How to scrape element form scraped url? Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Ok, let's say I have a website that has listed job offers and there are multiple pages (dynamic, that why I'm, using selenium). What I want to do:

1. **Scrape** every job post URL on multiple pages,
2. **Scrape** from every URL few items (title, localization, etc.)

```
class JobScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jobscraper"
    allowed_domains = ['pracuj.pl']
    total = 10
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/it%20-%20rozw%c3%b3j%20oprogramowania;cc,5016/%c5%82%c3%b3dzkie;r,5?rd=10&pn={}'.format(i)
        for i in range(1, total)
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.options.headless = True
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\kacpe\OneDrive\Pulpit\Python\Projekty\chromedriver.exe',
                                       options=self.options)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        res = response.replace(body=self.driver.page_source)

        offers = res.xpath('//li[contains(@class, "results__list-container")]')
         for offer in offers:
            link = offer.xpath('.//a[@class="offer-details__title-link"]/@href').extract()
            yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//h1[@data-scroll-id="job-title"]/text()').extract()
        yield {
            'job_title': title
        }
```

And it doesn't work, an error that occurred:

> TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got list

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 2):

You call `extract` in this line:

```py
link = offer.xpath('.//a[@class="offer-details__title-link"]/@href').extract()
```

Extract returns a list of elements, which is why you get the error when you try to pass `link` to `Request`.

Depending what you wanted to do, you could do `for link in links` and `Request` each result, or get a specific `xpath` by using `find_elements_by_xpath`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need selenium to scrape the required content. Turns out that the items you wish to grab from that site are within some script tag. Once you scoop out that portion using regex and process it using json library, you should access them very easily. The following is how I meant:

```
import json
import scrapy

class JobScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jobscraper"
    total = 10
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/it%20-%20rozw%c3%b3j%20oprogramowania;cc,5016/%c5%82%c3%b3dzkie;r,5?rd=10&pn={}'.format(i)
        for i in range(1, total)
    ]

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36'
    }
    def start_requests(self):
        for start_url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(start_url,callback=self.parse,headers=self.headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.css("script:contains('window.__INITIAL_STATE__')::text").re_first(r"window\.__INITIAL_STATE__ =(.*);")
        for item in json.loads(items)['offers']:
            yield {
                "title":item['jobTitle'],
                "employer":item['employer'],
                "country":item['countryName'],
                "details_page":item['companyProfileUrl']
            }
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Great tip! Could you explain to me how did you get all URLs by this method? You didn't set any selectors and I don't get it.

Comment: Navigate to that link and then press ctrl + u which will lead you to page source. Now, press ctrl + F and then look for any title available in that page. The search result should lead you to the script tag within which all the desired results are available. The above script only processes the content of that tag.

Comment: Yes, you have right. Thank you so much :)